# How use_sim_time works?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, use-sim-time, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on VIORB SLAM which using both camera and imu. I have to make the system work without ROS, but currently I successfully run the recorded datasets using use_sim_time only. This [link](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic) and [link](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/Clock.html#A.2BAC8-use_sim_time_parameter) doesn't provide me any detail in depth about how it work. Can anyone explain me how use_sim_time works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288672/how-use_sim_time-works?/) by [Rasp](https://answers.ros.org/users/34639/rasp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation you link to does describe how it works. As stated in section 2, when the parameter `use_sim_time` is true, the ROS API used to get times (e.g. `ros::Time time = ros::Time::now()`) will retrieve time data from the `/clock` topic rather than using the system clock. If you have something publishing time values to that topic (such as `rosbag` or Gazebo) then this means any nodes using the ROS time APIs will act as though the time is what `/clock` says it is.

If you turn `use_sim_time` off then any time values published to `/clock` will be ignored, meaning that any data published by `rosbag` will have time stamps that are different (probably massively different) from the current system time, and so data processing nodes may ignore that data as being out of date.

The `/clock` topic is useful for more than just playing back older data. If you write your nodes to process data based on times from the `ros::Time` API and not from its own loop, then you can effectively slow down and even stop the functioning of your system by controlling the `/clock` topic. This is particularly useful when working with simulations.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasp](https://answers.ros.org/users/34639/rasp/) on 2018-04-25**:
thank you so much, I finally understand it.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-09-07**:
does using `use_sim_time` have any effect on the values of `/clock` that are published by `rosbag play --clock`?